# Ruby on rails - Redirect to previous url after authentication with devise/omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, devise, omniauth

I'm using `devise gem` along with `omniauth gem` for Facebook, Twitter & Instagram. Below is the `gem`'s I use:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-instagram'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'instagram'
```

I followed [this toturial](http://willschenk.com/setting-up-devise-with-twitter-and-facebook-and-other-omniauth-schemes-without-email-addresses/) for Setting up Devise with Twitter and Facebook.

Inside my `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` I have set up `generic_callback` function like this:

```
def generic_callback( provider )
    @identity = Identity.find_for_oauth env["omniauth.auth"]
    @user = @identity.user || current_user
    if @user.nil?
      @tempUser = User.find_by_email(@identity.email) unless @identity.email.blank?
      if @tempUser.nil?
          @user = User.create(email: @identity.email, display_name: @identity.display_name, avatar: @identity.avatar, provider: @identity.provider || nil )
      else
        @user = @tempUser
      end
      @identity.update_attribute( :user_id, @user.id )
    end
    if @user.email.blank? && @identity.email
      @user.update_attribute( :email, @identity.email)
    end
    if @user.persisted?
      @identity.update_attribute( :user_id, @user.id )

      @user = FormUser.find @user.id
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: provider.capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

Everything works fine and what I want to achieve is to **redirect** user to **previous url** when they **sign_in** or **sign_up**.

Before setting up `omniauth gem` and only used `devise gem`, I used this method in my `application_controller.rb`:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/ || request.fullpath =~ /\/macbook1/
end
```

This did the magic when using only `devise`, but now if this method is inside the `application_controller.rb` I get this error:

[image: Error after sign_in or sign_out]

I also tried this with error:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if request.env['omniauth.origin']
      request.env['omniauth.origin']
    end
  end
```

What do I need to do to be able to `redirect` user to **previous url** after **sign_in or sign_up**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `application_controller.rb` you need 2 methods: `store_location` & `after_sign_in_path_for`.

*`application_controller.rb`*

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    after_filter :store_location

    def store_location
      return unless request.get?
      if (request.path != new_user_session_path &&
          request.path != new_user_registration_path &&
          request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
          request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
          request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
          request.path != "/users/edit" &&
          request.path != destroy_user_session_path &&
          !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
        session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath
      end
    end

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path || request.fullpath =~ /\/admin/
    end

end
```